# Clicking a button on a application is not working

Tags: vbscript

Hi I am trying to click the next button on an application using VB script but the next button dialog box is getting highlighted but it is not proceeding please see the code below and provide me some suggestion,
   `Dim objShell`
`Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`
   `Wscript.Sleep 4000`
   `objShell.SendKeys "%{N}`

Comment: Are there two items with N as the accelerator. If so send an enter after selecting with Alt + N.

Comment: For Alt N only i have mentioned like %{N}

Comment: ALT+N is to select the next button so as per VB Script i mentioned like this.

Comment: We need to see the dialog.

Comment: Use {TAB} instead of using "%{N}" to move across fields and use {ENTER}

Answer (score 0):

After highlighting the next button, you need to send an enter key to click.

objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

By the way, send Key method is not very robust but it is still acceptable as long as the windows is focused.